# @IntegrationTest vs @WebIntegrationTest annotations

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

In Spring (Boot), what is the difference between `@IntegrationTest` and `@WebIntegrationTest`?

According to documentation both annotations supply a fully loaded application server listening on usual ports.

Comment: Well I think the documentation is clear: `@IntegrationTest`: *If your test also uses @WebAppConfiguration consider using the WebIntegrationTest instead.*, `@WebIntegrationTest`: *This annotation can be used as an alternative to @IntegrationTest and @WebAppConfiguration*. From this I would assume that `@IntegrationTest` with `@WebAppConfiguration` is the same as `@WebIntegrationTest`.

Comment: Thanks @BohuslavBurghardt, I must've missed that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@WebIntegrationTest = @IntegrationTest +  @WebAppConfiguration